contructor passportStrategy
I have a problem with my strategy for the acccess_token, it happens that if I don't pass anything to the constructor, the validate doesn't return anything, and if I pass something like this I don't use it, it returns the payload, why is this?
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { jwtPayloadDto } from '../dto/JwtPayloadDto.dto';
import { EncoderService } from '../encoder.service';

@Injectable()
export class acTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'laprimera',
    });
  }

  validate(payload: jwtPayloadDto) {
    console.log(payload);
  }
}


